# How to connect to the gitlab from jenkins with token? You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository'

Tags: git, jenkins

I have unexpectedly error `remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.` in Jenkins job.

I also got this error when I try to pull from repo in the console and resolved this issue in the follow way:

```
git remote set-url origin https://valentyn.hruzytskyi:[TOKEN]@gitlab.com/url_to.git
```

So the token is correct and I try to set this token for connection:

[image]

But I can't found this connection profile and I steel can't connect to the git from Jenkins:

[image]

How to use the token connection in the Jenkins correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the access token you're using has the correct scopes/permissions. For this kind of use, it needs to have either `read_repository` or `write_repository` depending on your needs. If it doesn't you'll have to create a new token and give it the correct scopes. You can view your access tokens at `example.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens`